# Vue router failure

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I use a `Vue router` in a web application in identification page, when I enter first time login and password.
Web page loads a second time with changing the path
form 'http://localhost:8080/#/login' to 'http://localhost:8080/?#/login', when I try it again, the second time the router work well and i can enter the site

**vue router**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import routes from './routes';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

// configure router
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes, // short for routes: routes
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  scrollBehavior: (to, from ,savedPosition) => {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition;
    }
    if (to.hash) {
      return { selector: to.hash };
    }
    return { x: 0, y: 0 };
  }
});

export default router;
```

I use a navigation guard which work well.

```js
async function guardMyroute(to, from, next)
{
  if(store.state.token) {
    const payload = {
      access_token: store.state.token,
      Nom: store.state.Nom
    }
    let Data = await axios.post('/token', payload).then((res => res.data))
    if (Data === true) {
      next(); // allow to enter route
    }
    if (Data === false) {
      next({path: '/Home'});
    }
  }
  else{next({path:'/Home'});}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a different history mode? Maybe HTML5 mode will fix this issue for you. Add history: createWebHistory() to VueRouter options.

Comment: I tried but it s not working, all the site Is broken when i changes the history mode. I think i ve to configure the server